# Generated space by the harmonic oscillators $e^{iw}$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponential-function, fourier-series, lp-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{T}$ represent the $[0,1)$ interval and for each $w\in\mathbb{Z}$ denote the function $$e_w:\mathbb{T}\to\mathbb{C}$$ such that $$\forall x\in\mathbb{T}, \ e_w(x)=e^{2\pi iwx}.$$ It is known that the set of harmonic oscillators $e_w$ is a complete system in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$, i.e. such spaces are "generated" by $\big\{ e_w : \ w\in\mathbb{Z} \big\}$ with coefficients in some specific set of series $\ell^q\subset\big\{(c_w)_{w\in\mathbb{N}}: \ c_w\in\mathbb{C}\big\}$ since the set of finite sums $\big\{ \sum\limits_{w=0}^{k} c_we_w\big\}$ is dense in it, that is

> $\forall f \in L_p(\mathbb{T}), \ \exists (c_w)_{w\in\mathbb{N}}\in \ell^q \ 
> \Big( \lim\limits_{k\to \infty} \sum\limits_{w=0}^{k} c_w e_w = \ f \Big)$.

For each $p\in (0,\infty], \ (c_w)_{w\in\mathbb{N}}$ lies in a specific set of complex series $\ell^q$ where $1=\dfrac{1}{p} + \dfrac{1}{q}$.

My question is: given the set of *all* complex sequences $\{ (c_w)_{w\in\mathbb{N}} : \ c_w\in\mathbb{C}\}$, What is the space generated by the topological closure of the finite sums $\sum\limits_{w=0}^{k} c_w e_w$ ? In other words, What is
$$\overline{\bigg\{ \sum\limits_{w=-n}^{n} c_w e_w : \ n\in\mathbb{N}, \ c_w\in\mathbb{C}\bigg\} } \ ?$$

Evidently, several of these funcions reach infinite values in various subsets.

Comment: What do you mean by 'orthogonal' in $L_p$?.

Comment: You are right, I just corrected it! Orthogonality only makes sense when $p=2$.

Comment: Closure under what topology?

Comment: Take a usual one: in set theory, $f\subset \mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{C}$, both $\mathbb{T}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ with the usual open-balls topology, and $\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{C}$ with the Product (Tychonoff) Topology.

Comment: There is something wrong with your literal formulation. E.g., the way you're writing it, the $e^{iw}$ are just numbers, not functions. Don't you want to talk about functions $\psi_n(x)=e^{2\pi inx}$ on $[0,1]$, instead? If you rewrite in such terms, your question would be much clearer...

Comment: I have rewrote it. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: are you actually asking how the completion of a power series space looks like ?or the completion of some quotient of a power series space ?

Comment: That $\{ u_n\}$ is dense in $X,\|.\|$ doesn't mean that for any element $f \in X$ there is a sequence of complex numbers $(c_n)$ such that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \|f-\sum_{n=1}^N c_n u_n\| = 0$ ! It means that for any element $f \in X$ there is $(c_{n,N})$ such that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \|f-\sum_{n=1}^N c_{n,N} u_n\| = 0$ (try with $u_n(x) = x^n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n u_n$ converges in $L^q([0,1])$ iff it converges uniformly to an analytic function for $|x| \le r < 1$)